# How to change default character set in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8

I use MYSQL database, in which i want to change the default character set to "UTF-8" for all columns of all the tables present in the Database. 
As it contains lot of tables its not possible to do it manually.
Is there any way to do it more easily?

Whatever I did search, i understand that in  mysql information_schema.columns Contains the info about columns of all Database. Is there any way we can change the values in information schema.columns table?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to declare the default charset? Then you can just set the default charset on a database level and it will apply to all future columns. Or do you mean you already have a bunch of tables and columns which have already been explicitly set to some other charset and you want to retroactively change it?

Comment: yes i already have tables with different character set and now i want to change it. @deceze